# Option Strict ON prohibits operands of type object for operator &

Tags: vb.net

I have a code like this and have just added

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
```

to the top of the file.

```
   For Each dr As DataRow In issues.Rows
       _issuesList &= ", " & dr(table.PKeys(0).Name)
       If issueError.PROBLEM = "MISSNG" Then _myList &= ", " & dr(issueError.NotFound)
   Next
```

Now it doesn't compile and gives error on this part of the code:

```
dr(table.PKeys(0).Name)
```

Error:  `Option Strict ON prohibits operands of type object for operator &`

I have coded in C# and just had to make some changes in VB.NET code,  What is this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to cast the value from your data row, add `.ToString` after `dr(table.PKeys(0).Name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on what I mentioned in the comments, `Option Strict` enforces strongly typed data types, and does not implicitly cast values to string, int, etc.  The value coming from the datarow value is of a generic type, and without option strict turned on, this would normally be implicitly cast.  The error being thrown basically indicates that you're trying to concatenate a string to a datarow value, as opposed to two strings.